# Error upgrading Project Tango v1.23 Xiaotong for Java

Tags: java, google-project-tango

My Project Tango tablet upgraded the Project Tango Core to the latest today (v 1.23) and I started getting an error within my application.

```
10-06 17:10:21.219    5986-6168/? E/tango_client_api﹕ TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Internal Error: Connect failed internally: -2
10-06 17:10:21.227    5986-6168/? E/Face﹕ error invoked by message localize
com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoInvalidException
        at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.throwTangoExceptionIfNeeded(Tango.java:645)
        at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.connect(Tango.java:380)
at com.aawhere.homeaware.AreaLocalizer.connect(AreaLocalizer.java:274)
```

The error was introduced upon the upgrade and confirmed to be caused by the Project Tango Core upgrade since I have another tablet with the old core that runs my app just fine.

I attempted to upgrade the [Java sdk jar](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/downloads) to match the v1.23, however, Android Studio complained that the artifact is corrupt.

[image]

I confirmed that the artifact is corrupt by unzipping it using my macbook pro:

```
    Aarons-MacBook-Pro:Downloads aroller$ unzip -t TangoSDK_Xiaotong_Java.jar
    Archive:  TangoSDK_Xiaotong_Java.jar
        testing: META-INF/                OK
        testing: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF     bad CRC ce9003f9  (should be ee027fb2)
        testing: com/                     OK
        testing: com/google/              OK
        testing: com/google/atap/         OK
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/   OK
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/Tango$OnCloudUpdateListener.class   bad CRC dfe2bf5c  (should be 0bc3b5fc)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoCameraIntrinsics.class   bad CRC f6596bc1  (should be 7fddc109)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoCameraPreview.class  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoCoordinateFramePair$1.class   OK
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoTextureCameraPreview.class   bad CRC 0566a02b  (should be 77d47cbe)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/Tango$CloudEvent.class   bad CRC e7a3c664  (should be f290368b)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoXyzIjData$1.class  (incomplete l-tree)  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoCoordinateFramePair.class   bad CRC 5a10208b  (should be 908529ac)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoConfig$1.class  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoEvent$1.class   bad CRC 5f1c55e3  (should be 7990d785)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/Tango.class  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoAreaDescriptionMetaData.class   bad CRC c3172101  (should be 16c37a47)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoCameraIntrinsics$1.class   bad CRC f0c230af  (should be ecb0a6e8)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoPoseData$1.class   bad CRC 3e2b0fce  (should be a936782f)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoOutOfDateException.class   OK
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/Tango$1$1.class  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/Tango$1.class   bad CRC 8f43fbb7  (should be a87b49a9)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoAreaDescriptionMetaData$1.class   bad CRC 96e741e6  (should be 6c173e8a)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoEvent.class   bad CRC 21a1e8dc  (should be 97ca41d0)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoInvalidException.class  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoXyzIjData.class   bad CRC b64da24f  (should be b1195693)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoCameraPreview$MainRenderer.class  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoPoseData.class   bad CRC 06e43b62  (should be 921ae719)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TextureRenderer.class   bad CRC 20c0b15e  (should be 9ac80bf0)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoErrorException.class   bad CRC 211c0bfe  (should be 4ab8a808)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoException.class   OK
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoConfig.class   bad CRC 5b76d2f0  (should be f79fa86b)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/Tango$OnTangoUpdateListener.class   bad CRC 93316a02  (should be dc4a5f2e)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/   OK
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoMesh$1.class   bad CRC 89bf368e  (should be a1b0f741)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoPositionData$1.class   bad CRC 05b71fa4  (should be 6a1e7833)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoMesher$OnTangoMeshVectorAvailableListener.class  (incomplete l-tree)  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoNavigation.class   bad CRC c9876b22  (should be 1634dedc)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoReconstructionMetadata.class   bad CRC 60273ff9  (should be f96e65f1)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoMeshVector$1.class   bad CRC 3afbe150  (should be 17b10c19)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoMesh.class   bad CRC bebdc7c9  (should be a807de6d)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoMeshVector.class   bad CRC 650d0e5f  (should be 9f8094d4)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoPositionData.class   bad CRC 1d01c311  (should be d8c40f80)
        testing: com/google/atap/tangoservice/experimental/TangoMesher.class  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tango/   OK
        testing: com/google/atap/tango/TangoJNINative.class  (incomplete l-tree)  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
        testing: com/google/atap/tangohelperlib/   OK
        testing: com/google/atap/tangohelperlib/BuildConfig.class   bad CRC 0238628f  (should be 5693a5b2)
    At least one error was detected in TangoSDK_Xiaotong_Java.jar.
```

Can anyone confirm the jar file is corrupt or is it just my system?

Comment: Hi it is indeed a corrupted file, a new file is uploaded to the downloads page, please redownload the sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customer support responded to my request and replaced the Java download with a valid jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Just downloaded TangoSDK_Xiaotong_Java.jar from the download page.

The SHA-1 checksum for the downloaded file is invalid. I get the following :

> SHA-1 5c749a5c717be91c2f3c0b9c060f63e7639be861 tangosdk_xiaotong_java.jar

which doesn't match the checksum displayed on the download page.

Also tried to unzip it afterward, and the archive is corrupt.

I'm on a Windows 7 machine.

edit : i also upgraded the Core component to 1.23 on the device and i'm not having any apparent issue at the moment. I didn't upgrade the SDK though.

Comment: Thanks François.  I emailed Tango support.